# ADT7420 Temperature reading -Verilog

Tags: verilog, temperature

I have the following code to try and read the ADT7420 on my nexys4DDR FPGA board.   I can't seem to get it to work.  All of the led's wind up set to on, and I can't find the problem.  Where am I going wrong?

```
reg [5:0] SD_COUNTER = 6'd0;//counter used for the sending all the signals     to the temperature sensor
   reg [31:0] count= 32'h00000000;//counter used for slow clock
//since we are using SDA as inout we cannot use it inside the always block. I created a temp. reg SDI
    reg SDI;//register used for sending signals to temperature sensor inside the always block
    reg SCLK; // clock used inside the always block which is equated to the SCL at the end.
    reg dp = 1'b1;//decimal point for 7 segment display
    reg [18:0] Counter; // temp. counter for multiplexing seven segment display
// these are the registers used for 7 segment display
    reg [3:0] first;
reg [3:0] second;
reg [3:0] third;
reg [3:0] fourth;
reg [3:0] fifth;
reg [3:0] sixth;
reg [3:0] seg;
reg [15:0] led_temp = 16'b0000000000000000;//temp reg used in always block to asssign sda values
reg CLK = 0;//slow clock
// code for slow clock(200k)
always @ (posedge clk)
begin
    count <= count + 1;
    Counter <= Counter + 1;

if (count == 32'h00030D40)//200k in hex
    begin
        count  <= 0;
        CLK <= ~CLK;
    end
 else 
    count <= count + 1;
 end
always @ (posedge CLK) //always on 200k clock
begin
    if (SD_COUNTER == 49)
        SD_COUNTER <= 1;
    else
        SD_COUNTER <= SD_COUNTER + 1;
end

always @ (posedge CLK)
begin

    case (SD_COUNTER)
        6'd0   :   begin SDI <= 1; SCLK <= 1; end //initial condition
        //START signal for I2C protocol
        6'd1    :   SDI <= 0;
        6'd2    :   SCLK <= 1;
//      SLAVE ADDRESS 0x4B
        6'd3    :   SDI <= 1;
        6'd4    :   SDI <= 0;
        6'd5    :   SDI <= 0;
        6'd6    :   SDI <= 1;
        6'd7    :   SDI <= 0;
        6'd8    :   SDI <= 1;
        6'd9    :   SDI <= 1;
        6'd10   :   SDI <= 0; //write (R/W =1'b0 bit)
        6'd11   :   SDI <= 1'bz; //ACK (acknowledge from slave) 
        // Address of register inside the temperature sensor (0x00, temperature register)
        6'd12   :   SDI <= 0;
        6'd13   :   SDI <= 0;
        6'd14   :   SDI <= 0;
        6'd15   :   SDI <= 0;
        6'd16   :   SDI <= 0;
        6'd17   :   SDI <= 0;
        6'd18   :   SDI <= 0;
        6'd19   :   SDI <= 0;
        6'd20   :   SDI <= 1'bz; //acknowledge from the slave
        //Re-Start signal for I2C protocol
        6'd21   : begin SDI <= 1; SCLK <= 1;end
        6'd22   :   SDI <= 0;
        6'd23   :   SCLK <= 1;
        //Slave Address 0x4B

        6'd24   :   SDI <= 1;
        6'd25   :   SDI <= 0;
        6'd26   :   SDI <= 0;
        6'd27   :   SDI <= 1;
        6'd28   :   SDI <= 0;
        6'd29   :   SDI <= 1;
        6'd30   :   SDI <= 1;
        6'd31   :   SDI <= 1;//read (R/W=1'b1 bit)(read from the temp. sensor)
        6'd32   :   SDI <= 1'bz;//acknowledge from the slave
//we are storing in the values in a temporary led register, so that we can see the values on the leds.
        //Reading and storing the temperature on led_temp(MSB)
        6'd33   :   led_temp[15] <= SDI;
        6'd34   :   led_temp[14] <= SDI;
        6'd35   :   led_temp[13] <= SDI;
        6'd36   :   led_temp[12] <= SDI;
        6'd37   :   led_temp[11] <= SDI;
        6'd38   :   led_temp[10] <= SDI;
        6'd39   :   led_temp[9]  <= SDI;
        6'd40   :   led_temp[8]  <= SDI;
        6'd41   :   SDI <= 1'bz; // acknowledge from the slave

        //Reading and storing the temperature on led_temp(LSB)
        6'd42   :   led_temp[7]  <= SDI;
        6'd43   :   led_temp[6]  <= SDI;
        6'd44   :   led_temp[5]  <= SDI;
        6'd45   :   led_temp[4]  <= SDI;
        6'd46   :   led_temp[3]  <= SDI;
        6'd47   :   led_temp[2]  <= SDI;
        6'd48   :   led_temp[1]  <= SDI;
        6'd49   :   led_temp[0]  <= SDI;
        6'd50   :   SDI     <= 1'b1; //acknowledge from the master 

        //STOP signal for I2C protocol
        6'd51  :   begin SDI <= 1'b0; SCLK <= 1'b1; end
        6'd52   :   SDI <= 1'b1;
       endcase

end
//assigning led_temp to led 
assign led = led_temp;  
//assigning the SCL(I2C clock) to either slow clock(200k) or SCLK. 
assign SCL = ((SD_COUNTER >= 4) & (SD_COUNTER <= 20) | ((SD_COUNTER >= 25) & (SD_COUNTER <= 49)))  ? ~CLK : SCLK;
//assignin SDA(I2C Serial data) to SDI
assign SDA = SDI;
```

Comment: This is one of those cases where you might get a better response over at http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using `SDI` as a tri-state, however a tri-state must be `wire` type; not a `reg`. Deliberately assigning `x` or `z` to a `reg` type is an indicator that value under this scenario is a don't care, allowing the synthesizer to *drive* the resulting net to any value (typically based on logic optimization). It is still *driven*, not tri-stated.

A tri-state should be a `wire` type, and the assignments should be simple:

```
wire SDI;
reg SDI_drv_en, SDI_drv_val;
always @(posedge clk) begin
  // ... assign SDI_drv_en & SDI_drv_val to known values (1 or 0), plus other logic ...
end
assign SDI = SDI_drv_en ? SDI_drv_val : 1'bz; // Simple tri-state driver
```

FYI:
Most RTL coding guidelines recommend never assigning a `reg` type to `x` or `z`.
It sounds like you are directly synthesizing your RTL code without simulating. It is recommended to simulate before synthesizing. It is easier to debug logic issues in simulation.
You may have other issues with your code, but this should be enough to get you in the right direction.

Comment: What is the best way to simulate an inout?  Do I want to make it an output only for the simulation?

Comment: The port should be `inout`. Something should be driving it when RTL sampling it; such as another module or the testbench.